# What does 'dimension' strictly mean?

Tags: vector-spaces

Ask a simple question but confusing me.

Case 1.
Take an Eucildean space $\Bbb R^3$ for example. $\Bbb R^2$ is one of its subspace with bases $[1,0]$ and $[0,1]$, and the dimension of this subspace is $2$. So for example $[a,b]\in\Bbb R^2$.

Case 2.
Now, bases $[1,0,0]$ and $[0,1,0]$ form a subspace in $\Bbb R^3$ with dimension $2$; however $[a,b,0]\in\Bbb R^3$.

However, $[a,b,0]$ is isomorphic to $[a,b]$

I am confused about both cases. Which one is true?

Comment: Both are true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **dimension** of a vector space $V$ is the number of elements in any basis of $V$. One can (and should) show that any two bases have the same number of elements, so the definition does not depend on which basis you pick in the first place.

There's nothing wrong in your example: $$V := \{[a, b, 0] : a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ has a basis $\{[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]\}$ of $2$ elements, so $\dim V = 2$. It is true that we usually view $V$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but that is irrelevant here: the dimension of a vector space is *intrinsic* to that space, that is, it doesn't dependent on whether or how it is contained inside another vector space.

Some properties of a vector space $V$ are extrinsic, that is, they depend on how they sit inside another vector space $W$ (and so are more rightfully considered properties of the pair $(V, W)$). One example is the **codimension** of $V$ in $W$, which is defined to be
$$\text{codim}_W V := \dim W - \dim V,$$ and in particular is the dimension of any complement of $V$ in $W$.

Answer (score 3):

As you have said in your question, the key word is **isomorphic**.  It is not strictly correct to say that ${\Bbb R}^2$ is a subspace of ${\Bbb R}^3$, because ${\Bbb R}^2$ is a set of pairs while ${\Bbb R}^3$ is a set of triples.

It is true that ${\Bbb R}^3$ has a subspace
$$V=\{(x,y,0)\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}\ :$$
this is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$, but not identical to $\Bbb R^2$.  Also, $V$ has a basis $\{(1,0,0),\,(0,1,0)\}$, not $(1,0),\,(0,1)\}$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't know about Chen but it did helped me